# Java Date toString in different format after loaded from database

Tags: java, mysql, date

How can I compare dates in a reliable way in Java before and after they are persisted? 
The problem I face is: When I create a new instance of java.util.Date it's toString() method returns a value including the day of the week and time zone:

```
Fri Feb 03 10:15:31 CET 2017
```

When I persist this date (EDIT: the Date object) in a database table and load it back into an entity the toString method returns a different format, depending on the database type:

```
In case of MySQL date: 2017-02-03
In case of MySQL datetime: 2017-02-03 10:24:34.0
```

I don't always have access to a formatter because to toString method may be called implicitly by another toString method in my application.

These questions arise for me:

1. How does the Date object know which format to pick when using
   toString?
2. How can I control for the new Date object that it shall
       represent a date only (that is, a day without the time fraction) in the first place?
3. What is the best practice to compare dates of persisted objects in
   unit tests between an object before and after loading it from a
       database ?

Answer (score 2):

## Use objects, not strings

Do not use strings to pass data to/from your database. Use objects. That is the purpose of [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity), to convert from the data types of your database to the data types (classes) of Java.

## Use java.time, not legacy classes

Do not use the legacy date-time classes such as `java.util.Date` as they are notoriously troublesome, confusing, and flawed. Now legacy, supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

> How does the Date object know which format to pick when using toString?

The format used by `toString` is hard-coded, not picked. You always get the same format from that method. And a poor choice of format, whereas modern libraries and protocols use standard ISO 8601 formats.

Among the many poor design choices in `java.time.Date` is behavior of the `toString` method applying the JVM’s current default time zone to a value that is actually in UTC. This creates the illusion of a time zone that is not actually present.

Better to avoid these strings. Pass and fetch objects rather than strings, between Java and database. Call `PreparedStatement::setObject` and `ResultSet::getObject` methods to work with `LocalDate`, `Instant`, and other such java.time objects.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … );
```

If your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) is not yet compliant with [JDBC 4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/jdbc_42.html), and cannot directly handle java.time objects, fall back to briefly using the java.sql types. Immediately convert those java.sql objects to java.time objects by calling new methods added to the old classes.

```
java.sql.Date myJavaSqlDate = myResultSet.getDate( … );
java.time.LocalDate ld = myJavaSqlDate.toLocalDate();
```

> How can I control for the new Date object that it shall represent a date only (that is, a day without the time fraction) in the first place?

Use the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class for a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone. This maps to equivalent of the SQL standard `DATE` type. You should be using a date-only type to define the column in your database.

> What is the best practice to compare dates of persisted objects in unit tests between an object before and after loading it from a database ?

The `LocalDate` class offers methods for comparison, such as `compareTo`, `isAfter`, `isBefore`, and `isEqual`. Other classes are similar.

This has all been covered *many* times on Stack Exchange. Please search for class names such as `LocalDate`, `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime`, `ZoneId`, and `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Comment: I don't use the Strings to persist the dates, I do persist the Date objects. I edited my post to make this more clearer. The thing it that you use the toString method in various places such as even in dubugging time in your IDE and the results were somehow magical to me. Now I have a better understanding. And thanks for giving me the hint on converting the JDBC Sql Date to Java 8 LocalDate. It looks like my old driver did not support it. The current one does and I will use it!