# Timestamp database value is showing as processed before processing

Tags: java

Usually this is just myself not using `SimpleDateFormatter` correctly, but during the process of getting the `Timestamp` field out of the database, before any processing happens, at the lowest level, the Timestamp value is being shown as

> 10-Nov-2017 10:19:46

Which looks like it's already being processed as something else.I was expecting YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss as the format.

The MySql database column is `some_column_name TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`and the code that loads this value is here;

```
public Object loadSingle(DBInterface obj, String operator, PreparedStatement ps)
{
    Object results = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try
    {
        Field[] field = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        Object working = null;

        if (rs.next())
        {
            working = obj.getClass().newInstance();
            for (Field fieldLoop : field)
            {
                if (!Modifier.isPrivate(fieldLoop.getModifiers()))
                {
                    fieldLoop.setAccessible(true);

                    if (fieldLoop.getType().getName().compareTo("java.lang.String") == 0)
                    {
                        fieldLoop.set(working, rs.getString(fieldLoop.getName()));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (fieldLoop.getType().getName().compareTo("java.util.Date") == 0)
                        {
                            fieldLoop.set(working, rs.getDate(fieldLoop.getName()));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (fieldLoop.getType().getName().compareTo("java.sql.Timestamp") == 0)
                            {
                                fieldLoop.set(working, rs.getTimestamp(fieldLoop.getName()));
                            }
```

All other objects that I'm working with, including many with `Timestamp` values are processing fine. I've debugged this and can see the point that is set after . Can anyone tell me why this might be?

========EDIT

The query it's actually performing is;

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE id = ? ";
ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setInt(1, id);
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Are you trying to figure out how to format a Timestamp?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Date toString in different format after loaded from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42021074/java-date-tostring-in-different-format-after-loaded-from-database)

Comment: Try debugging it and see which method is executed in your `if` statements. `getString()`, `getDate()` or `getTimestamp()`

Comment: I noticed this through the process of debugging, it hits the timestamp if else properly, the format is incorrect when getting the timestamp as a timestamp. I'm not manually formatting anything as you can see from the code.